# Dynamically build case class or schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given a list of strings, is there a way to create a case class  or a Schema without inputing the srings manually.

For eaxample, I have a List,

```
 val name_list=Seq("Bob", "Mike", "Tim")
```

The List will not always be the same. Sometimes it will contain different names and will vary in size.

I can create a case class

```
case class names(Bob:Integer, Mike:Integer, Time:Integer)
```

or a schema

```
 val schema = StructType(StructFiel("Bob", IntegerType,true)::
            StructFiel("Mike", IntegerType,true)::
            StructFiel("Tim", IntegerType,true)::Nil)
```

but I have to do it manually. I am looking for a method to perform this operation dynamically.

Comment: you can just use map or a loop to create the schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data type of the columns are the same:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val nameList=Seq("Bob", "Mike", "Tim")

val schema = StructType(nameList.map(n => StructField(n, IntegerType, true)))
// schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(
//   StructField(Bob,IntegerType,true), StructField(Mike,IntegerType,true), StructField(Tim,IntegerType,true)
// )

spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

If the data types are different, you'll have to provide them as well (in which case it might not save much time compared with assembling the schema manually):

```
val typeList = Array[DataType](StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType)
val colSpec = nameList zip typeList

val schema = StructType(colSpec.map(cs => StructField(cs._1, cs._2, true)))
// schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(
//   StructField(Bob,StringType,true), StructField(Mike,IntegerType,true), StructField(Tim,DoubleType,true)
// )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the fields with same datatype than you can simply create as

```
val name_list=Seq("Bob", "Mike", "Tim")

val fields = name_list.map(name => StructField(name, IntegerType, true))

val schema = StructType(fields)
```

If you have different datatype than create a `map` of fields and type and create a `schema` as above.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above only covered one aspect which is create the schema. Here is one solution you can use to create the case class from the generated schema:
https://gist.github.com/yoyama/ce83f688717719fc8ca145c3b3ff43fd